# Angular 2 - Unexpected Module declared by AppModule

Tags: angular, routes, ng-modules

I am new to angular and trying to separate my modules in Angular2 app having the following directory structure.

I have my module and other components declared in the AppModule, but I am getting an error in browser console that `Unexpected HomeModule declared by AppModule`

```
app
--authentication
---- htmls, ts, css
--home
----dashboard
--------html, ts, css
----representativs
--------html, ts, css
----home-routing.module.ts
----home.module.ts
--app.routing.ts
--app.module.ts
```

app.module.ts

```
import { routing } from "./app.routing"
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeModule } from "./home/home.module";

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, routing, HttpModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HomeModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [UserAuthenticationService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

home.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { RepresentativesComponent } from './representatives/representatives.component';
import { HomeRoutingModule } from "./home-routing.module";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        HomeRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        DashboardComponent,
        RepresentativesComponent,
    ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

home-routing.ts

```
const homeRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: "representatives",
                component: RepresentativesComponent
            },
            {
                path: "dashboard",
                component: DashboardComponent
            },
            {
                path: "",
                redirectTo: "dashboard",
                pathMatch: "full"
            }
        ]
    }
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(homeRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

app.routing.ts

```
import { AuthenticationComponent } from "./authentication/authentication.component";
import { HomeComponent } from "./home/home.component";

const routes: Routes = [
    { 
        path: 'auth/:action', 
        component: AuthenticationComponent 
    },
    {
        path: 'auth',
        redirectTo: 'auth/signin',
        pathMatch: 'prefix'
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent
    }
]

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Comment: You should declare child modules on the imports section of the parent module, and not on the declarations.

Comment: You should put this comment as an answer. It worked for me!

Answer (score 23):

You need to correctly import your `HomeModule` in the `imports` section, not `declarations`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, routing, HttpModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HomeModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [UserAuthenticationService]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

I recommend [this](https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/understanding-angular-modules-ngmodule-and-their-scopes-81e4ed6f7407) article which beautifully explains the @NgModule thing

Comment: This is the 10th time I'm making the same mistake. Thanks for correcting noobs like me.

Answer (score 0):

If someone has the same problem although he has made the recommended corrections, it's possible that the package.lock.json comes from another OS (by a commit for example) or is not up to date. It is therefore advisable to remove package.lock.json and send this command line: `npm install`